# Join on date in SQLalchemy considering only date and not time of the day

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I need to join two tables in SQLalchemy on datetime columns but I do not want to consider full datetimes but only date parts of them (join two rows with similar dates even if the time of the days are not equal).

Here is something I have right now

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
...
first = meta.tables["schema.first"]
second = meta.tables["schema.second"]
select = sq.select([
    first.c.id,
    first.c.date,
    first.c.value,
    second.c.value])
    .select_from(first.join(second, sq.and_(
        first.c.id == second.c.id,
        first.c.date == second.c.date
        # exact match between datetimes is currently needed
    )))
```

Comment: What DB are you running against?

Comment: It is a PostgreSQL DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To truncate the timestamps to day precision use the function [`date_trunc(text, timestamp)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) in PostgreSQL:

```
select = sq.select([first.c.id,
                    first.c.date,
                    first.c.value,
                    second.c.value])\
    .select_from(first.join(second, sq.and_(
        first.c.id == second.c.id,
        sq.func.date_trunc('day', first.c.date) ==
        sq.func.date_trunc('day', second.c.date)
    )))
```

In this case you could also alternatively cast the timestamps as dates:

```
sq.cast(first.c.date, sq.Date) == sq.cast(second.c.date, sq.Date)
```

Comment: is there any way to do the same thing with models?
stock_data = session.query(Stock_Data).filter().all()  
parity_data = session.query(Parity_Data).filter).all()
and join those stock_data and parity_data then filter?

Comment: The same will work using the Query API, it is built atop Core. Have a look at `Query.join()`.

Comment: Sadly, yes. I have tried to do that by 
stock_data = session.query(Stock_Data).join(Parity_Data, Stock_Data.Date == Parity_Data.Date).firtst() 
but when I do that I cannot reach stock_data.Parity_Data and throws exception which is 
'Stock_Data' object has no attribute 'Parity_Data'
when I checked the attributes of the stock_data  by stock_data.__dir__() it shows ['_sa_instance_state',
 'stock_id',
 'Volume',
 'Low',
 'Open',
 'id',
 'Currency_Close',
 'High',
 'Date',
 'stock',
 '__module__',
 '__tablename__',
.
.
.
.

 '__class__'] but not the attributes about Parity_Data

Comment: Have you defined a relationship between them? If you want to use object-like access to related entities, you'll need that. If not, just `session.query(Stock_Data, Parity_Data)` to fetch 2-tuples of stock and parity data.

Comment: No, they do not have a common feature. Ok the date is common but there might be the same date for different stocks. Mapping is like 
Stock_Data <N-1>Stock
Parity_Data<N-1>Parity
Stock and Parity also do not have direct relation but 
Stock has currency attribute like "GBP" 
Parity has parity_name attribute like "USD/GBP"
I extract information from them with 
parity = session.query(Parity).filter(Parity.parity_name.endswith(stock.currency)).first() 
then continue do you think I have a bad design ?

Comment: Sounds like you have the makings of a new question, though if it is of the form "Do I have bad design", then it might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you I did not want to ask a new question until being sure I do not have the answer here

Comment: My question is here maybe someone that sees can help. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252767/flask-database-design-with-orm

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func
first = meta.tables("schema.first")
second = meta.tables("schema.second")
select = sq.select([
    first.c.id,
    first.c.date,
    first.c.value,
    second.c.value])
    .select_from(first.join(second, sq.and_(
        first.c.id == second.c.id,
        func.DATE(first.c.date) == func.DATE(second.c.date)
    )))
```